# Zend_Db - How to use results from Zend_Db_Table_Select

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm forced to work with the Zend-Framework in my current project, but I'm stuck at a specific point. Unfortunately, the documentation of the framework is horrible and doesn't really help me at the moment. The solution is probably extremely easy, but i can't figure it out on my own.

I'm just trying to get something from my database, which i try to achieve with this code:

**BS_Model_Subshops.php:**

```
class BS_Model_Subshops extends BS_Lib_Model
{
    protected $_name = 'shops';
    protected $_username = '';
    protected $_password = '';
    protected $_primary = 'id';
}
```

**LoginController.php:**

```
public function authAction() {
    $shop= new BS_Model_Subshops();
    $id= filter_var($this->getRequest()->getPost('id'));
    $db_content= $shop->select()->where('id= '.$id);
    Zend_Debug::dump($db_content);

    ... more code ...
}
```

This gives me the following object as a result (warning: Huge object incoming):

```
object(Zend_Db_Table_Select)#85 (7) {
["_info":protected] => array(10) {
    ["schema"] => NULL
    ["name"] => string(5) "shops"
    ["cols"] => array(8) {
        [0] => string(2) "id"
      [1] => string(4) "name"
      [2] => string(8) "css_path"
      [3] => string(3) "mmz"
      [4] => string(17) "order_information"
      [5] => string(11) "code_suffix"
    }
    ["primary"] => array(1) {
        [1] => string(2) "id"
    }
    ["metadata"] => array(8) {
        ["id"] => array(14) {
            ["SCHEMA_NAME"] => NULL
        ["TABLE_NAME"] => string(5) "shops"
        ["COLUMN_NAME"] => string(2) "id"
        ["COLUMN_POSITION"] => int(1)
            ["DATA_TYPE"] => string(3) "int"
        ["DEFAULT"] => NULL
        ["NULLABLE"] => bool(false)
            ["LENGTH"] => NULL
        ["SCALE"] => NULL
        ["PRECISION"] => NULL
        ["UNSIGNED"] => bool(true)
            ["PRIMARY"] => bool(true)
            ["PRIMARY_POSITION"] => int(1)
            ["IDENTITY"] => bool(true)
      }
      ["name"] => array(14) {
            ["SCHEMA_NAME"] => NULL
        ["TABLE_NAME"] => string(5) "shops"
        ["COLUMN_NAME"] => string(4) "name"
        ["COLUMN_POSITION"] => int(2)
            ["DATA_TYPE"] => string(7) "varchar"
        ["DEFAULT"] => NULL
        ["NULLABLE"] => bool(false)
            ["LENGTH"] => string(2) "60"
        ["SCALE"] => NULL
        ["PRECISION"] => NULL
        ["UNSIGNED"] => NULL
        ["PRIMARY"] => bool(false)
            ["PRIMARY_POSITION"] => NULL
        ["IDENTITY"] => bool(false)
      }
      ["css_path"] => array(14) {
            ["SCHEMA_NAME"] => NULL
        ["TABLE_NAME"] => string(5) "shops"
        ["COLUMN_NAME"] => string(8) "css_path"
        ["COLUMN_POSITION"] => int(3)
            ["DATA_TYPE"] => string(7) "varchar"
        ["DEFAULT"] => NULL
        ["NULLABLE"] => bool(false)
            ["LENGTH"] => string(3) "100"
        ["SCALE"] => NULL
        ["PRECISION"] => NULL
        ["UNSIGNED"] => NULL
        ["PRIMARY"] => bool(false)
            ["PRIMARY_POSITION"] => NULL
        ["IDENTITY"] => bool(false)
      }
      ["mmz"] => array(14) {
            ["SCHEMA_NAME"] => NULL
        ["TABLE_NAME"] => string(5) "shops"
        ["COLUMN_NAME"] => string(3) "mmz"
        ["COLUMN_POSITION"] => int(4)
            ["DATA_TYPE"] => string(14) "float unsigned"
        ["DEFAULT"] => NULL
        ["NULLABLE"] => bool(false)
            ["LENGTH"] => NULL
        ["SCALE"] => NULL
        ["PRECISION"] => NULL
        ["UNSIGNED"] => bool(true)
            ["PRIMARY"] => bool(false)
            ["PRIMARY_POSITION"] => NULL
        ["IDENTITY"] => bool(false)
      }
      ["order_information"] => array(14) {
            ["SCHEMA_NAME"] => NULL
        ["TABLE_NAME"] => string(5) "shops"
        ["COLUMN_NAME"] => string(17) "order_information"
        ["COLUMN_POSITION"] => int(5)
            ["DATA_TYPE"] => string(4) "text"
        ["DEFAULT"] => NULL
        ["NULLABLE"] => bool(false)
            ["LENGTH"] => NULL
        ["SCALE"] => NULL
        ["PRECISION"] => NULL
        ["UNSIGNED"] => NULL
        ["PRIMARY"] => bool(false)
            ["PRIMARY_POSITION"] => NULL
        ["IDENTITY"] => bool(false)
      }
      ["code_suffix"] => array(14) {
            ["SCHEMA_NAME"] => NULL
        ["TABLE_NAME"] => string(5) "shops"
        ["COLUMN_NAME"] => string(11) "code_suffix"
        ["COLUMN_POSITION"] => int(6)
            ["DATA_TYPE"] => string(7) "varchar"
        ["DEFAULT"] => NULL
        ["NULLABLE"] => bool(false)
            ["LENGTH"] => string(1) "6"
        ["SCALE"] => NULL
        ["PRECISION"] => NULL
        ["UNSIGNED"] => NULL
        ["PRIMARY"] => bool(false)
            ["PRIMARY_POSITION"] => NULL
        ["IDENTITY"] => bool(false)
      }
  ... more unimportant stuff here ...
```

Now, for example, i just want the name or the css path. How can i get one of those? I'm not really familiar with Zend, even though I worked with laravel before, and I just have huge problems with understanding it since it's so complex and doesn't have a good documentation with examples.

The Webserver uses PHP 5.4 and Zend-Framework 1.9 if that's important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fetchAll` to get the name or the css path

Try below code.

```
public function authAction() {
    $shop= new BS_Model_Subshops();
    $id= filter_var($this->getRequest()->getPost('id'));
    $db_content = $shop->select()->where('id= '.$id);
    $result = $db_content->query()->fetchAll();
    foreach($result as $key=>$value){   
        echo "Name : ". $value->name;
        echo "</br>";
        echo "Css Path : ". $value->css_path;
    }
    Zend_Debug::dump($db_content);

    ... more code ...
}
```

you can also use `toArray` method of the rowset object to retrieving a rowset as an Array.

```
$result = $db_content->query()->fetchAll();
$row_array = $result->toArray();
```

Regards,

Comment: Awesome. This is exactly what i was looking for. I always thought that `fetchAll()` is similar to `select()`. Thank's a lot for your help, this works fine!